# Winforms control LostFocus event not firing when you click the form background

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, lost-focus

I have a custom ComboBox which opens a separate control when you click on the arrow of the ComboBox.  I would like to call the 'LostFocus' event handler to close the custom control when you lose focus of the ComboBox.

This works fine if you click onto another control such as a text box, however doesn't fire if you click on the background of the form.

I want to mimic the functionality of when you click off and close the dropdown of a normal combobox.

Comment: Perhaps its because until you move to another control it hasnt lost focus, why not used the dropdownclosed event?

Comment: That is by design.  You can only get LostFocus (prefer Leave) when the focus is actually lost.  There are a large number of controls in the toolbox that don't want the focus.  Like PictureBox, Panel, etcetera.  And Form.  Its child controls take focus, like your custom ComboBox.  Which is why dropdowns don't work this way, they use the Capture property.  Which ensures you can see mouse events even when the mouse is not inside the window.

Comment: I've tried the dropdownclosed, however I am not opening the dropdown as its a custom control so disable the drop down happening.  I did try leaving it open but I need to click on the other control which is opened, this automatically fires when the dropdown is open which I don't want. I need an event which fires when you click on the background, but can't find one.  Or perhaps just call whatever is called the same as when the dropdown is closed perhaps?

Comment: @HansPassant, I did try the Capture property but couldn't make this work, have you any simple examples you could provide which may point me in the right direction?

Comment: You are doing it wrong, we can't see you doing it wrong.  Simple examples are never that helpful, usually because what you are trying to do isn't simple.  Which is how you ended up doing it wrong.  And it is too simple, you only need the MouseDown to detect a click outside of the window rectangle and MouseCaptureChanged to detect the system canceling the capture.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Take a `bool` variable at `Form` level and make it `true` during combobox enter(GotFocus) event`. In`Leave(LostFocus)`event of`combobox`, make it`false`.

Subscribe to `Form MouseClick` event and check `bool` variable in this event. if `true` , call combobox leave event here.